# Matplotlib Color Bar Height equals image in Matplotlib v 3.0 Python 3.x Jupyter Notebook 5.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, colorbar

UPDATE the issue below is specific to Jupyter Notebooks which is the platform that I am teaching in. Any feedback on why plots would behave differently in Jupyter since the update (i think??) would be greatly appreciated.

---

Ever since updating to matplotlib 3.0 (I think this is the issue), the code that I used to use to create a colorbar that matches the height of a plot no longer works in  Jupyter Notebook. It does work however in other regular python tool environments like Pycharm, etc.  Rather than producing a plot and a colorbar, the colorbar extends over the entire width of the figure.

[The gallery here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_colorbar.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axes-grid1-simple-colorbar-py) Provides a snippet that used to work as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

Looking at Stack Overflow I see many posts on this topic and the solutions to them **used** to work in Jupyter. Has anyone else encountered this issue with the newest version of matplotlib and Jupyter? I am running notebooks version 5.7.0/

Here is what my output plot looks like (all colorbar, no plot visible)

[image: This is not the data - this is the colorbar covering my plot]

I've spent some time ensuring this is not a duplicate post here on SO. Can you help or suggest a work around please?

If by chance this is an environment issue - i'm using [this environment](https://github.com/earthlab/earth-analytics-python-env).

Many thanks for any constructive suggestions,
Leah

Comment: FYI - The code works for me using matplotlib 3.0.1

Comment: It does? I will try to update matplotlib now and see if it works wtih the update. i have 3.0.0. I also am running this in jupyter notebook. i will test it in pycharm as well.

Comment: Ok thank you @DavidG guess what? this is an issue specific to Jupyter Notebooks. I will update my post accordingly. I never thought about testing it in another coding environment / tool assuming it works the same regardless.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. I'm not too familiar with Jupyter so can't say what is causing this

Comment: I appreciate it. It turns out the update to matplotlib 3.0.1 fixes it in the notebook! i'll post this answer now just in case anyone else encounters it.

Comment: As to *why plots would behave differently in Jupyter*: This happens only with the inline backend, which produces png files from the images using the `bbox_inches="tight"` option. If you do the same outside juypter via `fig.savefig(.., bbox_inches="tight")`, you'd also see the same result.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i didn't understand however how this is a duplicate question! i do see the answer in the other post is the same answer but isn't the question about colorbars different from a axis of grids? please help me understand so i can avoid duplication in the future. much appreciated.

Comment: A duplicate does not necessarily need to be the same question. If the answer is the same, it would qualify as duplicate as well. However in this case, even the question is the same: An axes which is produced via `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` suddenly occupies the complete figure space. You do not need to avoid duplication at all cost. If you made sure to have searched by all possible means and not found an answer, asking the question is useful, because you would potentially use different wording. If it is then closed as dupe it is useful for everyone using the same wording as you in their search.

Comment: Ok gotcha! thank you so much for the clarification @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have to say this particular issue has been bugging me for a while now. i'm very happy to have found such a simple solution!